# Is there any idea to acess the third a tag link text or click the link with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Need to acess the link through selenium but can't

Done:

```
link1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'sidebar1269')]//div[contains(@class,'v1269 hidepiece')]//a[3]")
link1.click()
```

and also tried:

```
link2 = driver.find_element_by_id("c0380dac-366a-43db-a2d7-61031e3ac10c")
    link2.click()
```

Source Code:

```
    <div id="sidebar1269" style="wdith:260px; height:600px;overflow-y: auto;" class="normal" bis_skin_checked="1">
         <div class="v1269 hidepiece" id="0ba14fb5-f7b3-4667-bcf5-708eda61b09c" bis_skin_checked="1" style="display: block;">
                    <a href="#" class="MarkLable"></a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="TriggerMarkerClick('0ba14fb5-f7b3-4667-bcf5-708eda61b09c')"><img src="/Portals/0/1000.png" alt="" width="25"></a>

 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="TriggerMarkerClick('0ba14fb5-f7b3-4667-bcf5-708eda61b09c')">Candace Novak, DVM</a></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to click on Candace Novok ,DVM link?

Comment: @DipakBachhav yes i need to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath :

```
//*[contains(text(),'Candace Novak, DVM')]
```